# LDAP authentication on MediaWiki

Tags: apache, ssl, ldap, mediawiki, ca

I have an ubuntu webserver which runs Apache and hosts a MediaWiki (`wiki.foo.foobar.com`). I also have a Windows domain controller (`DC01.FOO.local`) on an other server. What I am trying to do is let my AD users login on the wiki with their domain account.

I have been trying to accomplish this using the LDAPAuthentication extension for the MediaWiki. The wiki is supposed to only be accessible via HTTPS. Right now it uses the standard apache SSL settings.

But this is where i am kind of clueless, do i have to create a CA certificate on the DC, install the CA cert on the webserver and make apache use the cert + key ?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this in your Apache configuration to start with. You'll need to get your AD's CA cert over to it:

```
LDAPTrustedMode SSL
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /path/to/DC/CA_cert
```

In your LdapAuthentication settings in MediaWiki's *LocalSettings.php* file you may only need the following options:

```
$wgLDAPDomainNames      = array("mywiki");
$wgLDAPServerNames      = array("mywiki" => 'dc01.foo.local');
$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array("mywiki" => 'sAMAccountName');
$wgLDAPBaseDNs          = array("mywiki" => 'dc=foo,dc=local');
$wgLDAPEncryptionType   = array("mywiki" => 'ssl');
```